# La visualización de mi proyecto en java no se ve igual

Tags: java, netbeans

Al momento de previsualizar mi proyecto en netbeans se ve de una manera que me agrada, pero al momento de ejecutar mi proyecto s eve diferente, cambia todo el diseño.

Ejemplo:

Imagen cómo se debe ver

[image: La manera en cual se debe ver]

Está es la forma de cómo se ve cuando ejecuto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: NetBeans tiene algo que se llama *`Look and Feel`*, que sirve para poder previsualizar / compilar tu programa con unos determinados estilos de interfaz gráfica. Es posible que en la previsualización de NetBeans tengas por defecto un Look and Feel y que en la compilación tengas indicado otro Look and Feel. Revisa [este tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) que tiene  varios enlaces para entender cómo funciona eso y poder cambiar el Look and Feel, sea en la previsualización, sea en la compilación final de tu programa.

Answer (score 1):

No especificaste tu versión de netbeans, pero en tu código que te genera el diseñador de formularios debes de tener algo similar a esto:

```
try {
    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
}
```

Ese código se encarga de poner un tema gráfico llamado *Nimbus*, y es el encargado de que tus botones se vean grisáceos en vez de azules, si no deseas que se vea así,  solamente tienes que quitar ese código.

Answer (score 0):

Como lo menciona Ruslan López si generas tu frame en netbeans hasta abajo o donde tengas tu main del frame ahi donde dice "Nimbus" cambialo por "Windows" y listo amigo

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Juegos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]